# reCAPTCHA v3 return false

Tags: recaptcha-v3

We are currently implementing reCAPTCHA v3 in our application and working for some cases. But most of the cases it returns false.

Please find the client side token generation code

```
grecaptcha.ready(function () {
            grecaptcha.execute('{key}', { action: 'submit' }).then(function (token) {
                document.getElementById("test-token").value = token;
                document.getElementById("test-form").getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
            });
        });
```

We are using httpclient to validate by passing email and token.
But most of the cases we are getting false as status.

What are the possibilities of failure status and how to resolve those ?
Can we able to track exact failure reason from response ?

Thanks in advance.